# Permission denied error for docker build command on RHEL

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, azure-pipelines, docker-machine

I'm trying to build a docker image using Azure Pipelines. At the build step, I got the below error.

`Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker deamon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/vxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

The pipeline is running on a self hosted agent. The agent is running as the user `agentuser`. I researched this error on various websites and found several questions here as well. Most of them provided a solution that involved performing the steps mentioned here [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/). To confirm if that is the correct solution, I logged in to the self hosted agent and tried to run the command `docker ps` with user `agent user`, and it worked fine without requiring sudo. Therefore I'm assuming the steps mentioned in Docker documentation will not fix it.

What could be the other reasons for getting this error?